# How to upload images to database in ionic 4 MYSQL & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I hope you can help me I want to insert the name of the image in my database as well as upload the file to my server but I have no idea how to do it

In found a tutorial of ionic 3 but it does not work in ionic 4 and I am a newbie in this.

The tutorial can be found under the name of:
"How to upload images from gallery and camera to database in ionic 3 app"

Does anyone have any idea how it would be done?

I have been able to fix what Camara upload & gallery access but the "UPLOAD" I get a lot of errors I guess it's because of the version

```
Upload(){

  var headers = new Headers();

  headers.append(“Accept”, ‘application/json’);

  headers.append(‘Content-Type’, ‘application/json’ );

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = {

      image:this.base64Image

    };

  let loader = this.loading.create({

  content: ‘Processing please wait…’,

});

loader.present().then(() => {

this.http.post(‘http://ionicdon.com/mobile/upload_data.php’,data,options)

.map(res => res.json())

.subscribe(res => {

 loader.dismiss()

 if(res==”Successfully_Uploaded”){

   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

     title:”CONGRATS”,

    subTitle:(res),

    buttons: [‘OK’]

     });

         alert.present();

 }else {

  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

  title:”ERROR”,

  subTitle:”Image could not be uploaded”,

  buttons: [‘OK’]

  });

  alert.present();

   }

 });

 });

  }
```

the errors that appear in general is all the code does not recoze anything

Comment: Please post the errors you get here, so that somebody cam help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Https Required

I notice you are trying to post to `http://ionicdon.com/mobile/upload_data.php`. The latest version of Android requires https as far as I know, unless you have done special setup instructions.

### Newbie learning curve

If you are a newbie then I don't recommend trying to follow an Ionic 3 tutorial to build an Ionic 4 app.

A lot of little things have changed and its very difficult to know which bits (just look how long the [breaking changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md) document is).

### Firebase

You will probably have more success by looking for Firebase tutorials to start off with..

This is newbie friendly because it handles all of the server side stuff for you, and makes it easy for you to implement logins and security as well which you are going to need. It's likely any image upload tutorial you find will just do the normal demo style thing of "oh this is how to put the image on the server don't forget to secure it, that's out of the scope of the tutorial".

There are generous free resource limits given so if you are just learning you have space to breathe, and by the time you hit the paid limits you will either be able to monetise your audience or you will be more experienced and be ready to tackle writing your own server-side stuff.